# Getting file info with ffmpeg, object file recognized as Audio?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm testing a C++ program that should iterate in a directory and find all multimedia files. I used an iteration routine, and for every file I tried using the libav functions to open the file, such as `av_find_stream_info` in order to find stream info. It works fine for multimedia files, such as video and images, but the problem is that it recognizes some files as audio or video, for example it sees an audio stream inside a .o file! I also tried to use `av_read_frame` and it worked fine, without errors! I would like to avoid filtering by extension, is there any other solution to find "playable" files?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a dark art. You have to rule out certain commonly-seen file types that can masquerade as media files. You want a package that has already done all the work for you, and that is the [`file`](http://www.darwinsys.com/file/) package and its `libmagic` component. (Your platform may already have it. If it's UNIXy, try `man 3 libmagic` or see if you have a `file-devel` package.)

Comment: Had to switch back to extension based filtering, then use ffmpeg only on the files that pass this filtering (avi, mpeg and so on). Thanks anyway for the suggestion!